# Display single date on a textbox having prev and next buttons

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, datepicker

I am using php MySql.
How do i display **Next** and **Previous** dates in a single text box.
And Scenario is  -  I am fetching **some data**(string) using mysql, on some date. I want to display the respective data on respective dates.

09/06/2014 - 'Good Morning'
10/06/2014 - 'Good Night'.

```
<input type="button" value="prev">
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="next">


<span class="date_data"></span> //To display data
```

For suppose -  I have 'Good Morning' string which is on june 8th.. And 'Good Night' on june 20th. So when i select 8th, by pressing **prev** it should display 'Good Morning'. And likewise when i go to 20th. it should display 'Good Night'

[My JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FRt5f/)

Comment: are you storing mysql data in json or some object to display it in html?

Comment: i am not using json.. i am storing in some object..

Comment: so please share that object code also, how are you using it in page. So that we can help you better.

Comment: $bstm=array();
 while( $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    $bstm[$row3['id']] = $row3; 
}
return $bstm;

Comment: And that $bstm contains date and respective strings.

Comment: can't you use a map with date as key and data as value?

Comment: Show the relavent php/jquery code you have so far for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your json data has the format something like this,

```
var date = [{
        "Date": "09/06/2014",
        "Message": "Good Morning"
    },

    {
        "Date": "10/06/2014",
        "Message": "Good Night"
    }, {
        "Date": "11/06/2014",
        "Message": "Good Evening"
    }
];
var index = 0;
$("#prev").click(function () {

    $("#txt").val(date[index].Date);
    $("#msg").html(date[index].Message);
    index--;

});
$("#next").click(function () {

    $("#txt").val(date[index].Date);
    $("#msg").html(date[index].Message);
    index++;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FRt5f/12/)

Comment: ok as u said.. My Data is in the format of JSON..  and i just wanted to compare these data of dates with jquery datepicker.. how do i achieve that?